# Is it possible to validate a String Property to see if it is a valid date using Data Annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a String Property for an entity. I am putting a Date value into it ie "01/01/2000" via a form. Is it possible to validate the data entered to see if it is valid ie:

Assuming UK Date format below:

"32/01/2000" not valid, 
"31/01/2000" valid, 
"test" not valid

My POCO EF Property code looks like:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = @"Not a valid date")]


public virtual string DateOfBirth
```

Should this work .... or......

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `RegularExpression` annotation, but that's gonna make things **messy** to say the least. You're best off just converting that property to be a `DateTime`.

Here's how you could do it using the `RegularExpression` (**shield your eyes**):

```
[RegularExpression("@(^((((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))|([1-9]))\x2F(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))|([1-9]))\x2F(([0-9]{2})|(((19)|([2]([0]{1})))([0-9]{2}))))$)", ErrorMessage = @"Not a valid date")]
public virtual string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the the DateTime Parse methods?

```
DateTime dob;
try
{
  DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(myString, ...)
}
catch
{
  // handle error...
}
// string entered is valid
```